# How can format my output exactly how it's asked?

Tags: c++

My output should be a downward arrow using stars.

However, it is not working and I am new to C++ and don't know how to manipulate loops.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

string operator*(const string& s, unsigned int n) {
    stringstream out;
    while (n--)
        out << s;
    return out.str();
}

string operator*(unsigned int n, const string& s) { return s * n; }

int main(int, char **)
{
    string space = " ";
    string mix = "* ";
    for (int i = 0; i<3;i++)
    {
        cout << space*i;
        for (int j = 3; j>= 0; --j)
        {
            cout <<mix*j << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Expected Result:

```
 * * *
  * *
   *
```

Actual Result:

```
* * *
* *
*
 * * *
* *
*
  * * *
* *
*
```

Comment: Hint: Get rid of `j` completely. You don't need it. After you remove the loop for `j` you need to change just `mix*j` to make use of `i`

Comment: What exactly is not working? Where do you need help with?  It seems like your code does "sort" but doesn't add spaces to your output. You need to have a specific question in order to get help, this isn't Burger King where you drive in say what you want and we will deliver it

Comment: thank you drescherjm! fixed the problem

Comment: Why did you remove the attempt and the output examples? They are key to a SO question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
cout << space*i;
for (int j = 3; j>= 0; --j)
{
    cout <<mix*j << endl;
}
```

to this:

```
cout << space * i;
cout << mix * (3 - i) << endl;
```

since you don't need a double loop in your main function, you have your inner loop in the first overloaded `*` operator.

Comment: I used `(3 -i)` instead of `i`

Comment: Yes, since you want a downward arrow, thanks @drescherjm!